# How can I generate system wide events on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

I would like to know how I can generate system wide events programatically on Windows. I am thinking of generating system wide events such as key presses, touch events and mouse clicks mainly.

Is it possible to generate these events with an user mode application or I need to write drivers for this? Any samples or links would be usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Would it be possible to generate TOUCH messages this way?

Comment: I seriously doubt it.  I don't see anything in the touch API to do this.  I'd suggest you start a new question dedicated to this.

Answer (score 1):

(What programming language are you using?) It's possible in regular applications. What you need are "hooks" which are supported by the Win32 API. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/netwin32hooks.aspx) is an article on hooking in C#. Some are using the [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) library.

EDIT:

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the help on this topic in the Win32 API itself.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am planning to use C# as programming language.